# How to find view by id in my own library?

Tags: android, module, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am building my own RecyclerView library with a custom Adapter. My custom Adapter depends on the *findviewbyid* command. I feel I cannot just create a layout since a library should be adaptable to any situation.

Do I need to find a different command then *findviewbyid* or is there a work around for this?

Comment: But what is the problem? define id  (`<item name="reservedNamedId" type="id"/>`) and try to find the view ... if it doesn't exists throw an error (simialr as `ListFragment` works - it expects `android.R.id.listview` exists in the fragment's layout)

Comment: I feel like I remember seeing something similar when I was going through other libraries to see how they accomplish this, is this a layout file then that contains this item and id? That seems like some obvious solution I am unaware of.

Comment: you deine it in `values` dir fx in `ids.xml` ... then you are free to use `R.id.reservedNamedId` in the code ... you should also make the documentation to the lib

Comment: Ah I follow. I was able to figure it out from there, thank you

Comment: you could also just set it to whatever fixed number. depending on where you do the findviewbyid it can lead to problems or not though or it can lead to problems for someone using the library in an extreme edge case.

so it would be better to use something else to find the view, if you want to avoid resource files. however, nowadays resource files with a library is not a big deal(as you can package them with it into .aar).

Answer (score 0):

Create an XML file called IDs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="name" type="id"/>
    <item name="new_item_layout" type="layout"/>
</resources>
```